# Loop through column and copy last row when before change

Tags: excel, vba

Rather new to VBA and could use some help. I have a list of opportunities, where thee opportunity can appear multiple times as it moves through the sales process. I am looking to run through column A and copy the last row of the opportunity before the opportunity code changes. Sometimes the opportunity will only appear once and the list of opportunities could change. I have no idea where to start with this one??

For example I would like to copy rows A4,A13,A17 and A18.

Comment: Have you at least tried recording a macro? That's sometimes a good place to start.

Comment: Will entries always be added at the bottom of the list so for opportunity X we could have an entry at row 5, then 10, then 15 and you only want to copy the last one in row 15? Where do you want to copy it to?

Comment: The entire data set can change, I would like to scan column A and copy the row where the before the number in column A changes. So if cells A1 to A3 have a 1 in them and cell A4 has a 2 in it. I want to copy the row for cell A3, so where the last time 1 is seen before it changes to 2

Comment: What you have tried so far?